# How to calculate the smallestWidth on android?

Tags: android, resolution, dpi

Resolution is **1920*1080** and the actual size is **5 inch**.

How to calculate the **smallestWidth** on android ?

Which the res folder should be used on the handset,including **drawable,values and layout** folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, i get the **dpi**:

**dpi** = root(1920*1920+1080*1080)/5 = 440.5

Then I use the formula to get the **samllestWidth** :

**samllestWidth**=1080/(dpi/160)=1080/(440.5/160) = 392.2

So the **smallestWidth** is 393dp

But if the manufacturer set the **dpi** to 480 , the **smallestWidth** will be :

**smallestWidth** = 1080/(480/160) = 360dp

Answer (score -1):

For example If have an image (1920*1080) and assume it as xlarge. You have to create suitable images for other sizes  in 3:4:6:8 scaling ratio.

if you have a bitmap drawable that's 48x48 pixels for medium-density screen (the size for a launcher icon), all the different sizes should be:

36x36 for low-density
48x48 for medium-density
72x72 for high-density
96x96 for extra high-density

You should look at http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html for detailed information.

[image]

Sizes

small   Resources for small size screens.

normal  Resources for normal size screens. (This is the baseline size.)

large   Resources for large size screens.

xlarge  Resources for extra large size screens.

Comment: Sorry , I don't think the answer is what i asked. I want to know how to calculate the smallestWidth from the Resolution and actual size. And if i new a android project, which res folder(drawable-xxhdpi or drawable-xhdpi , values-large or values-xlarge ,etc.) should be the appropriate to store the resources .

Comment: There are no more detailed information except the link i gave in the answer. Think , 1536x1152   1920x1152  1920x1200 are hdpi. So you can use drawable-hdpi for that. and you can calculate it with  3:4:6:8 scaling ratio.  8 -> 1920 then 3 -> ?.  3 * 1920  / 8 = 720 smallest size.